# Is it possible to reclaim files after incorrect unmount?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

When I first began using Linux (~10 yrs ago) I used a USB univ. drive adapter to mount an external hard drive. Unfortunately, I was not aware of the unmounting procedure so, when finished, I just unplugged the drive. Of course, now I cannot access it. I was hoping there was a way (w/o paying for it, if possible) to re-mount the drive and access the files. Anyone have any suggestions?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: If the data is on the disk but the files are corrupted you might have a chance. Go through the [questions tagged #data-recovery](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery?sort=votes) and read the answers. If the data is not on the disk then the answer is *no*. It hasn't been deleted from the disk, it has never been there and thus it cannot recovered.

Comment: Indeed, just search the web for solutions. First figure out what filesystem is on the drive, then use a suitable file recovery application to try and recover your data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but in all likelihood, the files were never written to the disk. Thus no recovery effort will help, even if you were willing to pay.

Unmounting flushes the content of the [disk write buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) from memory to the disk. If the buffers aren't flushed, the data is still only in memory, not on the disk.

If you pulled the disk out while a write from memory was taking place, it's possible that there's a small amount of data that was written to the disk but not yet registered as belonging to the file. However this would only be a few kilobytes, probably not worth any recovery effort.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I was transferring files **from** the external drive **to** the hard drive. All the files existed on the external drive so that is not the problem. It's getting access to them again, i.e., re-mounting the ex. drive, so I can transfer more of them to the hard drive.

Comment: @Lee Ah. I don't understand the problem then. If you have the drive that contains the files, what prevents you from accessing them?

Comment: Because I didn't unmount the drive, I just disconnected it. Now it won't read it.

Comment: @Lee What do you mean by “it won't read it”? Do you have trouble mounting it? What error messages do you get? What appears in the system logs? Are you sure the disk is still physically ok after this time?

Comment: What I mean is that it won't even read it. When I try to mount it nothing happens. It doesn't even see it Usually, the connection I am using is mounted automatically but not on this drive. I tried it on a different drive and it works perfect but not on the one I failed to unmount properly.

Comment: @Lee Does the drive spin up? Do any messages appear in the kernel logs? It sounds like the disk is broken.

Comment: No, it doesn't spin and I can't find anything in the error logs. I guess it is broken. But it worked just fine until I unplugged it w/o unmounting. Could that have done it?

Comment: @Lee If it doesn't spin up, the disk isn't working. Unplugging without unlikely to have caused that. Moving a disk while it's reading or writing can damage it, so if you pulled it out while it was actually busy, that could have done it, but the most likely explanation is that some speck of dust or humidity sneaked in the wrong place in the last decade.

Comment: [Sorry it took so long to get back ... I appreciate your help] So it would seem that the data is lost for good, is that correct?

Comment: You might have a 'stiction' issue. Try cooling the drive in your freezer, tapping it on the desk, or puttiing it i n another USB enclosure. Also check the power supply (if it had one). They go out a lot.